# How i can hide the "Apply Label" inside our site pages's properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, modern-experience, sitepages

I have created a communication modern site, and i created a custom site pages content type which include a managed metadata site column named "Properties", but now when i create a new modern page and update the page properties i will get a property named "**Apply Label**" as follow:-

[image]

so how i can hide this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable label settings through library settings? If it is true, select "None" and compare the results.​​

If the issue still exists, please refer to https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/modern-bug-cant-remove-apply-label-field-from-list/f8d8ac95-1cb4-4131-8905-21fe92adcd80

Answer (score 0):

Instead fixing the myriad of existing problems, MS forces "features" on us, without the option to remove them. I will never understand what on earth goes through the heads of the decision makers at MS.